# emulate windows path with symbolic links

Tags: ubuntu, windows, symlink, path

I have many files that refer to `N:/path/to/MainFolder`

I am working with Ubuntu, I do not use Windows and I have my MainFolder in my user directory.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a symbolic link that when `N:/path/to/MainFolder` is accessed, it actually accesses `/home/myUser/MainFolder`

Comment: _when `N:/path/to/MainFolder` is accessed_.  Accessed by what?  From where? Nothing in Unix is going to try to do that.  Is this directory available via some windows file sharing protocol?  Are you asking how to add the equivalent of a symbolic link in Windows?

Comment: You say that `MainFolder` is in your directory, yet you want to create it? What I would do is replace `N:\path\to\ ` in those files with `/home/my-user/`, and all other backslashes with slashes. You can use a text editor or `sed`. You can actually create a symbolic link `ln -s MainFolder "N:\path\to\MainFolder"`, but what if your file contains the path `N:\path\to\MainFolder\blabla`? The last backslash doesn't work in a UNIX filesystem.

Comment: I want to know if this is possible to avoid modifying the files